# Image handling with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, server

Hello and here is my question. I wrote a server that gets GET request from a javascript app, when clicking on a

which must change the content of a  without reloading the page but it is not working. Can someone give and advice? Thanks! Here is my code :
Node js :

```
else if (req.url == "/cats") {
        var chunk;
        fs.readdir('./Images/cats', function(err,data){
            if (err) throw err;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    console.log("data",data[i]);
                    var mime_type = path.extname(data[i]).substr(1);

                    fs.readFile('./Images/cats/' + data[i], function(er,pics){
                        if (er) throw er;
                        console.log("pics",pics);
                        chunk = pics;
                        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "image/" + mime_type});
                        res.end(chunk);
                    });
                }

            // res.end(chunk);
        });
```

And here is the JavaScript code that has to show the images in the

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


function catsAll(){
console.log("123");
xhttp.open("GET", "/cats", true);
xhttp.send();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var cats = document.getElementById('img');
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    console.log('abv');
    cats.innerHTML.src = '/cats' + xhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

}

And the HTMl itself ..

```
<li onclick="catsAll()"><a href="#"  >Cats</a></li>


<div id="img" >
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: innerHTML does not have a src.... innerHTML is a string of the HTML in the element

Comment: Consider this `cats.src = '/cats' + xhttp.responseText;` as `innerHTML` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I think you handle the response incorrectly.
Try this one below

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    console.log('abv');
    document.getElementById('img').src='/cats' + xhttp.responseText;
    }
```

That is because you are not updating the img element src with your current code.
You should not use the innerHTML property at all

Comment: IMO you should encourage the use of strict equality (===) for inexperienced developers. If you use strict equality everywhere (even when it isnt *really* required) you wont forget to use it when you actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things... one, you don't have an actual `<img>` tag in your HTML. You will need that if you want to display an image by either a) a link to it's location on the server or b) a data-url.

Two, you are trying to pass the actual image data back from the server as though it were a document, but I don't think you can assign that to an image tag. You would need it to be a [data-url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) which is a base64 encoded representation of the image the browser expects.

If you can, I would remove the server side entirely and let the browser do the work. Just change the src of the image to be the picture's location on the server (if you need to touch the server, just have it return a string representing the location of the image on the server).

**EDIT** 
thinking it through a bit more, your server side isn't far off if you could have it return a specific cat image resource based on an identifier. But if it is serving the cat image as a document, then you don't need the XHR request at all. Just change the source of the image.

```js
var i = 0;
function cats(){
  document.getElementById('img').src = "/cats/"+ (++i);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="cats()" />
<img src="" id="img" />
```